# Capybara: Use `within` for many `it` examples?

Tags: rspec, capybara

In a view test, I want to do the following (not exactly this, but it explains the point):

```
  within 'ul' do
    it { should have_selector 'li', text: 'Some text' }
    it { should have_selector 'li', text: 'Some other text' }
  end
```

Sadly, the `within` method seems to be available only within `it` blocks.

I could rewrite the specs to the following:

```
    it { should have_selector 'ul li', text: 'Some text' }
    it { should have_selector 'ul li', text: 'Some other text' }
```

But this seems redundant to me.

So: is there a way to specify a context for many `it` examples?

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't use the Capybara logic outside of `it`. You can, however, use multiple expectations within a single `it`, as follows:

```
it "should have selectors" do
  within 'ul' do
    should have_selector 'li', text: 'Some text'
    should have_selector 'ul li', text: 'Some other text'
  end
end
```

If you really need/want separate `it` blocks, then one approach is to use a "shared example", although that seems like overkill in this particular situation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `subject` to specify the ul element as the context of the exampless:

```
subject { page.find('ul') }
it { should have_selector 'li', text: 'Some text' }
it { should have_selector 'li', text: 'Some other text' }
```